# How to check space on a opensuse-linux-system?

Tags: linux, command-line, hard-drive, opensuse

I wanted to check the space that I have on the machine: I tried it with this command:

```
 df -h

linux-wyee:~ # df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
rootfs           20G  6.9G   12G  37% /
devtmpfs        1.9G  8.0K  1.9G   1% /dev
tmpfs           1.9G  604K  1.9G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs           1.9G  692K  1.9G   1% /run
/dev/sda13       20G  6.9G   12G  37% /
tmpfs           1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs           1.9G  692K  1.9G   1% /var/run
tmpfs           1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /media
tmpfs           1.9G  692K  1.9G   1% /var/lock
/dev/sda14      384G   46G  337G  12% /home
linux-wyee:~ # ^C
linux-wyee:~ #
```

Question: Did i catch all the paths and parts of the disc!?

What is wrong?

Do I have any free space left?

Comment: This question seems to be offtopic for StackOverflow, it's better directed at SuperUser, which is a sister site.  Good luck.

Comment: hello dear OmnipotentEntity - many many thanks - i will head over to the Superuser-site. Greetings zero

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On your home partition (the partition which holds all of your personal files), you have used 46GB out of 384Gb, which is 12% of your disk. You still have 337GB free.